# Generate numeric id in a range between 1 to 10

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script that dynamically combines a category name with an item id. It will then call images from a folder that match the file name. It consists of the file path, category name and item id e.g. Banking-1.jpg, Banking-2.jpg, etc.

```
var f = {
            image: "/img/" + this.item.Categories[0].Category + "-" + this.itemId + ".jpg"
}
```

Right now it just returns a value like Banking-50.jpg, for which there is no existing image. Is it possible to define a range so that the maximum value it can return is Banking-10.jpg?

Comment: Where does `this.itemId` come from?

Comment: There's an array of items I'm returning via Json. `this.temId` is the id for each item in the array.

Comment: Are you trying to change the code that returns the number, or if it returns higher then 10, use 10?

Comment: Yes, prefer to use 10 if the returned value is higher than 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cap the integer with the [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) functions. See the following example.

```
var f = {
            image: "/img/" + this.item.Categories[0].Category + "-" + Math.min(Math.max(this.itemId, 0), 10) + ".jpg"
}
```

This will work unless `this.itemId` is a string, in which case you will need to cast it to an integer with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
var f = {
            image: "/img/" + this.item.Categories[0].Category + "-" + Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(this.itemId,10), 0), 10) + ".jpg"
}
```

If you like, you can define a helper function like this.

```
function capToRange(i, min, max)
{
    return Math.min(Math.max(i, min), max);
}
```

And use it like this.

```
var f = {
            image: "/img/" + this.item.Categories[0].Category + "-" + capToRange(this.itemId, 0, 10) + ".jpg"
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Since `item.itemId` is an integer, the first method worked. Thank you.